# Can Replace String workflow delete characters?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I'm trying to use old SPD 2010 Workflow logic with a 2013 workflow feature.

In the past, I could blank fields by making an initiation form parameter called blankdata that was set as a string, and the value was set to nothing.

I could then set fields to blank by setting them to this blankdata value.

well...with the 2013 replace string feature, I figured I could use the same logic.  I tell the replace command to replace : with blankdata.

Generally, when I'm building and testing the workflow...when I first build the workflow and run it once... it works as expected.  but on every subsequent run... it doesn't do the replace.

so... not sure how to do what I want and replace certain characters with nothing in a string (basically deleting the characters).   is there a way to do this?  or have I hit a bug?